# Python generator inside custom class

Tags: python, generator

I'm in the process of learning Python and I'm trying to figure out why a function containing a 'yield' statement within a custom class does not act as expected.  My objective is for the function to act as a generator; that is, it returns a generator iterator which can then be used in a for statement.

The class is defined as follows:

```
class inclusive_range:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self._start = 0
        self._step = 1
        self._stop = num
        self._next = self._start

    # iterator implementation - would like to avoid this
    # def __iter__(self):
    #     return self
    #
    # def __next__(self):
    #     if self._next > self._stop:
    #         raise StopIteration
    #     else:
    #         _r = self._next
    #         self._next += self._step
    #         return _r

    # generator implementation - trying to get this to work
    def generator(self):
        if self._next < self._stop:
            _r = self._next
            self._next += self._step
            yield _r
```

The iterator implementation (commented out) works as expected when running this statement in the main program:

```
for i in inclusive_range(10):
   print(i)
```

where the output is the expected (prints the numbers 0 through 10 inclusive).

However, when I try using the generator as follows:

```
for i in inclusive_range(10).generator():
   print(i)
```

The output is only the single number 0.  At first I thought the generator() call was not returning an iterator as expected, so I used the debugger to investigate:

```
n = inclusive_range(10)

# I pulled up the "evaluate expression" window in the debugger and did the following:

n.generator().__next()__ # prints 0
n.generator().__next()__ # prints 1!
n.generator().__next()__ # prints 2!
n.generator().__next()__ # prints 3!

# ...and so on until StopIteration is raised.
```

So my question is...it appears to work as I would expect in the debugger, why is it only returning the first value otherwise?

Comment: BTW, "<" in this case should actually be "<=", sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the generator not being properly formed. You will want a loop, which `yield`'s the desired value while updating the object state to prepare to `yield` the next value. In short, you just need to replace your `if` with `while` in `generator(self)` and you should be good to go! This code worked for me (commented out code removed for clarity):

```
class inclusive_range:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self._start = 0
        self._step = 1
        self._stop = num
        self._next = self._start

    # generator implementation - trying to get this to work
    def generator(self):
        while self._next < self._stop:  # <-- while instead of if
            _r = self._next
            self._next += self._step
            yield _r
```

And the test:

```
> for i in inclusive_range(10).generator(): 
    print(i) 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks, makes sense as the execution of the generator is paused after yielding.

Comment: Exactly - generators are functions that keep their state after returning (yielding) a value. On the next call, they resume from where they were and should be formed in such a way to `yield` the next value as desired each time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement in your generator method:

```
# generator implementation - trying to get this to work
def generator(self):
    while self._next <= self._stop:
        _r = self._next
        self._next += self._step
        yield _r
```